# Complex scalar derivative of trace of complex matrices $\frac{d}{d z} Tr[A U(z) B U^H(z)] $

Tags: complex-analysis, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

I'm trying to numerically find the maximum of
$$
f(z) = Tr[ A\;U B\; U^H], \quad  U=U(z,z^*),\\
A,B,U\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n},\;\;
 A=A^H, \quad B=B^H
$$
using gradient descent(ascent) w.r.t. $z \in {C}$.
As I understand, I have to use gradient scheme
$z_{n+1} = z_n + \eta\;2 \frac{\partial f(z,z^*)}{\partial z^*}$,
so I have to calculate the derivative $ \frac{\partial f(z,z^*)}{\partial z^*}$. Here is calculation:
$$\begin{align}
&dTr[ A\; U B\; U^H] \\
&= Tr[ B\; U^H A\; \color{red}{dU }  ] + Tr[ B^T U^T A^T \color{blue}{dU^*}] \\
&\left< X:= B\; U^H A \right>\\
&= Tr[ X\;\; (U'_z\;\; \color{red}{dz} + U'_{z^*}\;\;\color{blue}{dz^*})  ] \\
&+ Tr[ X^* ({U^*}'_z \color{red}{dz} + {U^*}'_{z^*} \color{blue}{dz^*})] \\
& \left< \text{using } {f^*}'_z = (f'_{z^*})^*\text{ and } {f^*}'_{z^*} = (f'_z)^* \right>
\\
&= Tr[ X \;\;\; (U'_z \quad \color{red}{dz} + U'_{z^*}\quad \color{blue}{dz^*}) ] \\
&+ Tr[ X^* ( (U'_{z^*})^* \color{red}{dz} + (U'_z)^* \color{blue}{dz^*})]
\end{align}$$
 Denote $U'_z = V,\;\; U'_{z^*} = W$. Then
$$\begin{align}
dTr[] 
&= Tr[ X \; V + X^*  W^*] \color{red}{dz} \\
&+ Tr[ X \; W + X^*  V^*] \color{blue}{dz^*}
\end{align}$$
Finally $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^*} = Tr[ B\; U^H A\; W] + Tr[B\; U^H A\; V]^* $

Am I correct? I'm pretty unsure here, because I've never studied matrix or Wirtinger calculus.

(U(z) is squeeze operator here, if you are interested:)

Comment: You have changed the order of the arguments to the trace function in a non-cyclical manner. In your equation defining $f(z)$ the product order is $(AU^HBU)$, but in the differential expression the order is $(AUBU^H)$. The traces of these two products are not equal (unless $U$ is hermitian).

Comment: @greg, yes, thanks. This was a typo, my fucntion is $Tr[AUBU^H]$. Fixed. Now everything seems correct(?).

Comment: Okay, now everything looks right.

Comment: I have looked through you other answers and trust you. Unfortunately, I have no other sources of verification right now, so thank you with this "confidence-request" question! How do you think, should I answer to my question in order to mark it as solved somehow?

Comment: Your question is of a type that invites either a "yes" or "no" response, and such responses typically take the form of a comment. And that's okay. Had your solution been wrong then someone would write an answer containing the correct solution, and you could accept it.